# Blur the background image in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to make my background image blur? I came across some solution StackOverflow for some old way of doing it. I found it old and doesn't work well. So is there are a clean way to do it.

Comment: https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure so I just googled this and first answer I got was this one: https://www.android-examples.com/android-blur-application-background-image-programmatically/